# How to get last user with wpdb?

Tags: users, wpdb, select

can someone please help me with this query:

```
$ultimousuario = $wpdb->get_var( "SELECT TOP 1 FROM  $wpdb->users WHERE user_login = 'usuario*' ORDER BY user_login DESC");
echo "<p>O último usuário é {$ultimousuario}</p>";
```

We're trying to get the last user that contains "usuario*" at it's user_login, order by decrescent.

Comment: What do you mean by "last"? Most recently created, most recently logged in, ...? `user_login` is WordPress's term for "username", so ordering by that will just get you the username that's deepest in the alphabet.

Comment: If you *are* trying to get the `user_login` that's deepest in the alphabet starting with `usuario` (ie, if you have `usuarioAAA` and `usuarioZZZ`, and you want `usuarioZZZ`), then try changing `WHERE user_login='ususario*'` to `WHERE user_login LIKE 'usuario%'`.

Comment: I mean the last created, sorry.

Comment: is there a reason you're using raw SQL instead of the built in functions and classes?

Answer (score 4):

If you're trying to get the last user created with the username format `usuario*`, I'd recommend using `get_users()` instead of writing a SQL query.

```
$args = array(
    "search"         => "usuario*",            // Search string
    "search_columns" => array( "user_login" ), // Field(s) to search
    "order"          => "DESC",                // Search order
    "orderby"        => "user_registered",     // Order by this
    "number"         => 1,                     // Get only this many users
);
$user_objects = get_users( $args );
// Ensure we've got results
if ( ! empty( $user_objects ) ) {
    // Pull the 1st array element, which will be a WP_User object,
    // and use the get() method to extract the username to a variable
    $most_recent_usuario = $user_objects[0]->get( 'login_name' );
}
echo "<p>O último usuário é {$most_recent_usuario}</p>";
```

### References

- [`get_users()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_users/)
- [`WP_User_Query::prepare_query()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_user_query/prepare_query/) for the `$args` details
- [`WP_User::get()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_user/get/) to extract the `user_login` from the `WP_User` object